# Java varargs confusion?

Tags: java, oop

I have a problem with this code.

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}

public class TestExms {
static String s="-";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       A[] aa = new A[2];
       B[] ba = new B[2];
       sifter(aa);
       sifter(ba);
       sifter(7);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    static void sifter(A[]... a2){s+="1";}
    static void sifter(B[]... b1){s+="2";}
    static void sifter(B[] b1){s+="3";}
    static void sifter(Object o){s+="4";}

}
```

when i run this code out put will be "-434".
problem is why:
 this  `A[] aa = new A[2];` when pass to `sifter(aa);` this dose not call  `static void sifter(A[]... a2){s+="1";}` . It will call to this method `static void sifter(Object o){s+="4";}` 
Can some one please explain me this?
And what happen inside this `(A[]... a2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when pass to sifter(aa); this dose not call  static void sifter(A[]... a2){s+="1";} .

You gave a wrong syntax in `varargs` (seems confused).

You defined you function as

```
static void sifter(A[]... a2) {
        s += "1";
    }
```

Which means you are reciving an array of `A[]`'s   Not `A`'s.

It works when you change your signature as

```
static void sifter(A... a2) {
        s += "1";
    }
```

When you write

```
static void sifter(A[]... a2) {
        s += "1";
    }
```

That is equivalent of

```
static void sifter(A[] a1, A[] a2, A[] a3) { // and so on 
        s += "1";
    }
```

Hence when you pass an A[] to it's treating the While array as a `Object` and not `A[]`

Comment: *You gave a wrong syntax in varargs* no really.. worth to note that when you remove the method `sifter(Object o)` from the program `sifter(aa);` is valid call to the method `sifter(A[].. aa);`